# Unit testing "invisible"/"implementation dependent" private fields?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Well I have a unit that does some really expensive calculations. (I have  decently high resolution heatmap-images captured by a high speed camera from a windtunnel experiment and I need to calculate the airspeed based on the heat transfer per time during a linear part).

Typically a prelimenary calculation "takes" between 10 seconds and a few minutes for a single "timeframe and test".
However for a different timeframe, a lot of the calculations are "similar". So at some point I started adding a caching of the calculations.

Now this is completely internal to the class, without any visibility to the outside world (As it should be).
I can test if the "caching is correct" by running the calculations on a "hot" and a "cool" class.

However how would I check that the cached value is even stored at all? Should I try to inspect the private stat? Also at the moment this is just a project for me learning to C# (implementing old projects from python); if this project was based on TDD, how would I write a TDD test description to describe such a caching property? The only visible external indication is that "the function is a few times faster". But I can't test against that really.

Comment: In general I'd try separating the caching behaviour from the class. If you use the decorator pattern etc you can compose the caching behaviour. Then can test your class and test decorator caching implementation separately

Comment: While @GraemeMiller is definitely correct, in that you have two distinct behaviours, you can use Microsoft Fakes and shim the calls to caching to ensure that it is called as expected.